# The for statement returns before the while statement ends

Tags: android, json, for-loop, while-loop

Based on today's date, I have created a code that adds one year to the future.

```
val calendarObject = JSONObject()
val calendarArray = JSONArray()

val currentCalendar = calendar.clone() as Calendar

val futureCalendar = calendar.clone() as Calendar
futureCalendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1)

do {
    val timeFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd", Locale.getDefault()).format(currentCalendar.timeInMillis)
    calendarObject.put("date", timeFormat)
    currentCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
    Log.d("Activity", "TEST while $timeFormat ${calendarObject.getString("date")}")
    calendarArray.put(calendarObject)
} while (currentCalendar.timeInMillis != futureCalendar.timeInMillis)

for (i in 0 until calendarArray.length()) {
    Log.d("Activity", "TEST for ${calendarArray.getJSONObject(i)}")
}

inputObject.put("calendar", calendarArray)
```

The log taken with `TEST while` shows that the date is added day by day.
[image]

However, up to two `TEST for` outputs, and the same date is included in the saved json format file.
[image]

Why is this happening and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Is it running on two separate threads?

Comment: I'm not sure what your title means, but you're modifying and putting the same `JSONObject` object over and over. Move the `val calendarObject = JSONObject()` line into the `do`-`while`.